# Как сделать аргумент метода в виде названии таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mvc

В метод пишу аргумент таблицы. Дальше мне нужно сделать запрос. Но вот проблема, это не работает.

Вот так это работает, но как я понял, это плохо со стороны безопасности сайта

```
# Проверка на существование поста
public function isExists($id, $table)
{
    $vars = [
        'id' => $id,
    ];
    return $this->db->column("SELECT `id` FROM $table WHERE `id` = :id", $vars);
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы это работало вот так:

```
# Проверка на существование поста
public function isExists($id, $table)
{
    $vars = [
        'id' => $id,
        'table_checker' => $table
    ];
    return $this->db->column("SELECT `id` FROM :tablechecker WHERE `id` = :id", $vars);
}
```

Это PHP MVC.
Класс Database:

```
<?php

namespace application\core;

use PDO;

class Database 
{

protected $db; // Protected поле db в него помещается соединение с базой данных

// Конструктор помещает в определенные поля, нужные параметры
public function __construct() 
{
    $config = require 'application/configs/db.php';
    extract($config);
    $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf8;', $username, $password);
    $this->db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}

// Метод query отвечает за выполнение запроса через mysql
public function query($sql, $settings = []) 
{
    $preparedRequest = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    if (!empty($settings)) {
        foreach ($settings as $k => $v) {
            if(is_int($v)) {
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            } else {
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
            $preparedRequest->bindValue(':'.$k, $v, $type);
        }
    }
    $preparedRequest->execute();
    return $preparedRequest;
}

// Метод row отвечает за выполнение select запроса через mysql в определенном виде
public function row($sql, $settings = []) 
{
    $result = $this->query($sql, $settings);
    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

// Метод column отвечает за выполнение select запроса через mysql в определенном виде
public function column($sql, $settings = []) 
{
    $result = $this->query($sql, $settings);
    return $result->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: имя таблицы сделать свойством класса

Comment: всё что внутри if `(!empty($settings)) {` выкинуть, оставить только `$preparedRequest = $this->db->prepare($sql); $preparedRequest->execute($settings);`

Comment: в методе row() **очевидно** поменять `fetchAll()` на `fetch()`, плюс добавить метод `all($sql, $settings = [], $mode = 0) { return  $this->query($sql, $settings)->fetchAll($mode)`

Comment: в конструкторе [задать дефолтный способ фетча, включить режим выброса исключений и отключить режим эмуляции](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql#example)

Comment: В остальном отличный класс, послужит верой и правдой.

Comment: @Ипатьев, дико извиняюсь, не могли бы Вы загрузить куда - либо исправленный код, пожалуйста

Comment: какой именно? класса Database или того в котором isExists?

Comment: @Ипатьев Желательно оба, благодарю

Comment: однако губа не дура. Ну вот например [второй](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253882/a-lightweight-crud-based-on-the-table-data-gateway-pattern). Вместо своего exists вполне можешь использовать read().

Comment: @Ипатьев, я понял, как это сделать, то есть добавлением поля, но со стороны безопасности сайта, это нормально будет выглядить?

Comment: повторяю: для безопасности сайта **имя таблицы надо сделать свойством класса** и брать из этого свойства